# SQL Server 2005 One query to calculation two table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm beginner in SQL Server

I have three tables in Database hospital

1. PatientFiles
2. OtherServices
3. PatientDeposit

Two queries to display my result

- Query Number One.  Display PatientFilesID, TotalOtherServices

  ```
  SELECT pf.ID AS PatientFileID, SUM(os.Quantum * os.Price) AS TotalOtherServices
  FROM PatientsFiles pf INNER JOIN OtherServices os ON pf.ID = os.Patient_File_ID 
  WHERE pf.ID = '14'
  GROUP BY pf.ID
  ```

It is true result

```
    PatientFileID  | TotalOtherServices
        14                194.00
```

- Query Number Two.  Display PatientFilesID, TotalPatientDeposit

  ```
  SELECT pd.Patient_File_ID AS PatientFileID, SUM(pd.Deposit) AS TotalPatientDeposit
  FROM PatientsDeposits pd
  WHERE pd.Patient_File_ID = '14'
  GROUP BY pd.Patient_File_ID
  ```

It is true result

```
    PatientFileID | TotalPatientDeposit
        14               450.00
```

- My very tired to mix two queries

  ```
  SELECT pf.ID AS PatientFileID, SUM(os.Quantum * os.Price) AS TotalOtherServices, 
  SUM(pd.Deposit) AS TotalPatientDeposit
  FROM PatientsFiles pf
  INNER JOIN OtherServices os ON pf.ID = os.Patient_File_ID  
  INNER JOIN PatientsDeposits pd ON pf.ID = pd.Patient_File_ID
  WHERE pf.ID = '14'
  GROUP BY pf.ID
  ```

It is false result

```
    PatientFileID  | TotalOtherServices | TotalPatientDeposit
         14                  582.00         1350.00
```

Thank you for help me in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select pf.ID as PatientFileID,
    os.TotalOtherServices,
    pd.TotalDeposit
From PatientFiles pf
    Left Join
 (Select Patient_File_ID as PatientfileID, SUM(os.Quantum * os.Price) AS TotalOtherServices
  From OtherServices Group By Patient_File_ID) os on pf.PatientFileID = os.PatientFileID
    Left Join
 (Select Patient_File_ID AS PatientFileID, SUM(Deposit) AS TotalPatientDeposit
  From PatientsDeposits Group By Patient_File_ID) pd on pf.PatientFileID = pd.PatientFileID
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, it looks like the values are 3 times bigger than expected.
(194 * 3 = 582, 450 * 3 = 1350).

Also, in your 2nd query you aren't using a `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT pf.ID AS PatientFileID, 
SUM(pd.Deposit) AS TotalPatientDeposit
FROM PatientsFiles pf INNER JOIN PatientsDeposits pd
ON pf.ID = pd.Patient_File_ID
WHERE pd.Patient_File_ID = '14'
GROUP BY pd.Patient_File_ID
```

I know that this is not the answer & more of things that should be checked.

Comment: yes the value bigger than 3 times expected
but in tow query i don't use INNER JOIN because all result in one table

Comment: @Ramy: I have modified the query. Now it includes 1 column from PatientsFiles table. Can you try & see the result with this query?

Comment: I want mix two queries 
Mix queries is number 3 query
Thanks